# Select first word of string in Spark.SQL

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I am trying to select the first word in the string of column Office_Name in table Office_Address thru Spark SQL. I am using below query -

```
select split_part(Office_NAME,' ',1) Office_Alias from world_Location.Office_Addrsss
```

It works fine when I query in redshift database but fail when I try to run it thru spark.SQL inside Python Script (Glue Job)

Error It shows

```
AnalysisException: "Undefined function: 'split_part'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 165 pos 55"
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error

> AnalysisException: "Undefined function: 'split_part'. This function is
> neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function
> registered in the database 'default'.; line 165 pos 55"

because `split_part` is not a part of the built-in spark api available [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html).

Instead, you may try using [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#split) with the index `0` since you are interested in the first word separated by space eg.

```sql
select split(Office_NAME,' ')[0] Office_Alias from world_Location.Office_Addrsss
```

Comment: Note [`split_part` is now part of spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#split_part) as of v3.3.0